# IIS 10 switches from HTTP/2 to HTTP/1.1 when Response.Flush is called in an application pool configured in classic mode

Tags: windows, http, iis, http2, http.sys

We are trying to implement the HTTP/2 protocol in the technical preview 3 of Windows 2016 but the connections switch to HTTP/1.1 when Response.Flush is called in an ASP.NET application configured in classic mode. In that case the protocol switch to HTTP/1.1 with chunked transfer-encoding. We don't have the problem when the application pool is configued in integrated mode.

Does there exist a workaround excepted using integrated mode to keep all connections in HTTP/2?

Comment: perhaps better ask this on superuser.com ?

Comment: @Marged, you mean Server Fault, right?

Answer (score 0):

This is becouse HTTP/2 on IIS does't support buffer flush.

Comment: Hi Andrey, welcome to stack overflow.  @Lionel's original question was `Does there exist a workaround excepted using integrated mode to keep all connections in HTTP/2?` and I'm not sure you answer that in your answer.